# Bread crumbs In grails

Tags: grails, navigation, uinavigationbar, breadcrumbs

I want to know the usage and implementation of the bread crumbs in grails.

i have some gsp(view) pages ,Home page is default i have 6 categories and in that 6 sub pages i need to show the navigation path in my pageslike
    home/grocery/sub grocery.... 
    home/finance/subfinance...

i need to show the page navigation.

```
        <div id="heder_content">
        <g:if test="${session.user }">

 <div id="bread_crumbs"style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:474px;height:80px;width:800px">
         </div>
        </div>
        </g:if>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would you like to achieve exactly? You can try creating a taglib where you read the controller name and the action, and passing some parameters you can display the name of your product for example. 
I mean something like this:

```
<g:breadcrumb title="${product.name}" />
```

and in your taglib file:

```
    class BreadCrumbTagLib {
            def breadcrumb = { attrs ->
                 def title=attrs.remove('title')
                 out << '''<div id="bread_crumbs"style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:474px;height:80px;width:800px">${controllerName} / ${actionName} / ${title} </div>'''
            }
    }
```

My example is very simple, but I hope you get the idea! If you need something more complex, I suggest you to get a look at: http://adityakalia.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/breadcrumbs-framework-for-grails/

Comment: i have some gsp(view) pages ,Home page is default i have 6 categories and in that 6 sub pages i need to show the navigation path in my pages    like        home/grocery/sub grocery.... page navigation. home/finance/subfinance...

Comment: You can pass as argument what you need. For example your category and subcategory, and get a breadcrumb like: `<g:breadcrumb title="${product.name}" category="${product.category}" subcategory="${product.subcategory}" />` I hope I give you the idea!

Comment: i got the idea on what you said and helped me. at final i want to remove the home image in breadcrumbs and place my text over there is it possible